# How much can we infer internal structure from a hologram?

Tags: hologram

How much can we infer internal structure eg of an arbitrary object, like a sphere or cell, from a holographic interference pattern on its surface?

Comment: The answer is "nothing at all" unless that holographic interference pattern is somehow correlated to what's on the inside.  Am I misinterpreting what you mean by  holographic pattern on its surface?

Comment: Cort has nailed it, unless you have in mind some particular object where there is some correlation between surface and inside. Are you thinking of any class of object in particular - for example, probing the inside of a body by surface textures induced by acoustic vibrations? Otherwise, in general, surface and inside are in principle independent: one can print different diffraction patterns on the same ball.